# Fetching item by unique firebase id in angularfire 1.0.0

Tags: arrays, angularjs, key, firebase, angularfire

I have trouble fetching one unique item from my firebase using angularfire 1.0.0. To clarify, I want my app to fetch a post given a unique firebase id e.g. "-JkZwz-tyYoRLoRqlI_I". It works when navigating in the app e.g. clicking on a link to a specific post, but not on a refresh. My guess is that it has something to do with synchronization. Right now it works when fetching all posts and use it in a ng-repeat. This is a clue to why it works for one item when navigating to the page. This should probably not be hard since this should be a pretty standard operation, but i can't get it to work. I have searched everywhere but there is actually no guide on this. In the API they refer to `$getRecord(key)`

> Returns the record from the array for the given key. If the key is not
>   found, returns null. This method utilizes $indexFor(key) to find the
>   appropriate record.

But this is not working as expected. Or am i missing something?

It works for ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="postt in posts">
   <div>
      <h1>{{postt.title}}</h1>
      <div>{{postt.timestamp}}</div>
      <div>{{postt.content}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But not for unique items like this:

```
<div>
   <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
   <div>{{post.timestamp}}</div>
   <div>{{post.content}}</div>
</div>
```

This is the service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.module.blog.post')

.factory("PostService", ["$firebaseArray", "FIREBASE_URL", function($firebaseArray, FIREBASE_URL) {

    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "posts");
    var posts = $firebaseArray(ref);

    return {
        all: posts, // ng-repeat on this works fine

        last: function(nr) {
            var query = ref.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(nr);
            return $firebaseArray(query); // ng-repeat on this work fine to
        },
        create: function (post) {
            return posts.$add(post);
        },
        get: function (postId) {
            console.log(postId); // This is -JkZwz-tyYoRLoRqlI_I
            var post = posts.$getRecord(postId);
            console.log(post); // This print null
            return post;
        },
        delete: function (post) {
            return posts.$remove(post);
        }
    };
}]);
```

As the comments say in the get function, the postId is there and posts is also set, but the post is null.

This is the controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.module.blog.post', [])

.controller('PostCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'PostService', function($scope, $routeParams, PostService) {

    // This returns e.g. postId "-JkZwz-tyYoRLoRqlI_I"
    console.log($routeParams.postId);

    $scope.post = PostService.get($routeParams.postId);    
    $scope.posts = PostService.all; // Illustrates the example not actually in this controller otherwise

}]);
```

This is what is an example on what is in the firebase database

```
<myfirebase>
 posts
 -JkUnVsGnCqbAxbMailo
 comments
 content: ...
 timestamp: ...
 title: ...
 -JkZwz-tyYoRLoRqlI_I
 comments
 content: ...
 timestamp: ...
 title: ...
 -JkhaEf9tQy06cOF03Ts
 content: ...
 timestamp: ...
 title: ...
```

I find this problem very wierd since it should be very standard. I am obviously missing something, but can't work it out. Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know that the documentation of the [$getRecord()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-getrecordkey) function is kind of misleading. What you actually get from `$firebaseArray` is a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) of an array. It means that your `posts` variable will contain your posts at some point in the future. That being said, it seems that the `$getRecord` function only works when the promise have been resolved, i.e. when the array has been downloaded from Firebase. To make sure that the promise is resolved when you call the `$getRecord` function, you can use `$loaded()` on the promise :

```
var posts = $firebaseArray(ref);
posts.$loaded().then(function(x) {
    var post = x.$getRecord(postId);
    console.log(post);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
});
```

If you are wondering why it works for `ng-repeat`, it's because Angular knows that the `posts` variable is a promise and waits for it to be resolved before rendering the values.

Comment: This solved my main problem after putting the the $loaded() in my controller and then assign the $scope.post. Thanks alot!

Comment: It would be great to hear how the docs are misleading and why one would expect data that has to be loaded from a remote server to appear instantly. Feel free to reach out to support with feedback.

Comment: It is stated in the API under $getRecord, https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-getrecordkey that:

`var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
var rec = list.$getRecord("foo"); // record with $id === "foo" or null`

This indicates that the `$getRecord("foo")` could be called directly after the list was created. This do not work, which is a bit misleading in my opinion. Would be nice with a ref to the `$loaded` doc.

Comment: Hi Kato, I should have said "The $getRecord() function documentation" instead of the firebase documentation. Like Mattias said, I think that the $getRecord() function documentation / example can be a bit misleading for someone who is not really into Angularjs... I'll send my feedback to the support team!

Answer (score 2):

This is happening due to promises.

- Along the lines of what Kato, Jean-Philippe said, `$firebaseArray` is not immediately available as it needs to be downloaded.
- See the [`.$loaded()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-loaded) documentation:

> `.$loaded()` "returns a promise which is resolved when the initial array data has been downloaded from Firebase. The promise resolves to the $firebaseArray itself."
>   
>   That answers your question, and I just wanted to show another way of doing it:

- This is a great use case for extending AngularFire services.

  - As the [AngularFire API Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html) says:

> "There are several powerful techniques for transforming the data downloaded and saved by `$firebaseArray` and `$firebaseObject`. These techniques should only be attempted by advanced Angular users who know their way around the code."
>
> Putting all that together, you accomplish what you want to do by:
>
> - Extending the Firebase service [`$firebaseArray`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray)
> - Following the documentation for **[extending services](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-extending-the-services)**.
>
> ### Example

- Here is a working [JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/sinanbolel/156my15q/) I put together that is tied to one of my public Firebase instances.
- It's important to note that you should add `".indexOn":"timestamp"` to your rules for `/posts`.

#### Factories

```
app.factory('PostsArray', function (FBURL, PostsArrayFactory) {
    return function (limitToLast) {
        if (!limitToLast) {
            console.error("Need limitToLast");
            return null;
        }
        var postsRef = new Firebase(FBURL + '/posts').orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(limitToLast);
        return new PostsArrayFactory(postsRef);
    }
});


app.factory('PostsArrayFactory', function ($q, $firebaseArray) {
    return $firebaseArray.$extend({
        getPost: function (postKey) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var post = this.$getRecord(postKey);
            if (post) {
                console.log("Got post", post);
                deferred.resolve(post);
            } else {
                deferred.reject("Post with key:" + postKey + " not found.");
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        createPost: function (post) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            post.timestamp = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
            this.$add(post).then(function (ref) {
                var id = ref.key();
                console.log("added post with id", id, "post:", post);
                deferred.resolve(ref);
            }).
            catch (function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    });
});
```

#### Controller

```
app.controller("SampleController", function ($scope, PostsArray) {

    var posts = new PostsArray(5);
    $scope.posts = posts;

    $scope.newPost = {};
    $scope.createNewPost = function () {
        posts.createPost($scope.newPost);
    }

    $scope.postId = '';
    $scope.getPost = function () {
        posts.getPost($scope.postId).then(function (post) {
            $scope.gotPost = post;
        }).
        catch (function (error) {
            $scope.gotPost = error;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Very nice input! I have now extended the $firebaseArray. However, the above example only work on button click and not on a call on refresh. I used the $loaded function on promise and now it works fine.

Comment: Yep! It was just an example, not necessarily a direct application of your question since Jean-Philippe already provided an answer for your use case. You can also put the `$loaded()` in the controller and run the get and create functionality _not_ on button click.