# getting single objects out of $angularfire/$firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to follow a tutorial on lynda.com which uses angularfire (angularjs firebase) except it uses stuff like $firebase.$asObject and such, which is now obsolete.  I tried to look at the documentation as well as some other SOF questions, and I finally found something that worked, but it looks ugly and seems quite inefficient since the only way I found for it to work is to iterate through all the objects in an array returned from the database.  This array holds all the users which are registered.  This is how I got it to work, but can someone tell me the correct way to do it, because this does not seem like it should be it.

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var auth = firebaseAuth(ref);

auth.$onAuth(function(authUser){
    if(authUser){
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users/');
        var stuff = firebaseArray(ref);

         ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.val() !== null) {
                var keys = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
                for(var key in keys){
                    if(keys.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                        if(authUser.uid === snapshot.val()[keys[key]].registeredUser){
                           rootScope.currentUser = snapshot.val()[keys[key]];
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                console.log('location does not exist');
            }
          });

        var user = firebaseObject(ref);
        //console.log(user);
        rootScope.currentUser = user;
    } else {
        rootScope.currentUser = '';
    }
});
```

Here is what my firebase forge looks like:

[image: Firebase Forge]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'll write a more detailed answer later, but here are some examples of  `$firebaseArray` and `$firebaseObject` - [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164753/retrieve-record-with-query-angularfire/29188996#29188996)  [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129341/fetching-item-by-unique-firebase-id-in-angularfire-1-0-0/29134163#29134163) [(3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129341/fetching-item-by-unique-firebase-id-in-angularfire-1-0-0/29134163#29134163). Have you looked through the [AngularFire getting started guide]?(https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/)

Comment: By the way, getting a single record from a `$firebaseArray` is done with [`$firebaseArray.prototype.$getRecord(key)`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-getrecordkey).

Comment: the problem that I'm having seems to be that I can't get the generated unique key that firebase makes for each entry in the array.  I am trying to use the auth object to match which user is logged in with their data in the database, but the auth object doesn't contain "JIZ4VPSfzPNvpnPvlli" for the example user posted above.  If I had access to that key from the user logging in, getting the data would be much easier.  Maybe I am just looking at this the wrong way, though.

Comment: I didn't really describe what's going on that well.  Basically when you create a new user on the registration page all that firebase stores with its authentication service is the email and password, but I also add some entries into the database including that user's first and last name.  Those are what I'm trying to retrive when the user logs back in, but the unique key generated by firebase is not stored in the authenticated user object, so I am trying to figure out an efficient way to access the user's info in the database with the information provided from the authenticated user object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a single record from AngularFire collection synchronized from Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309537/how-can-i-get-a-single-record-from-angularfire-collection-synchronized-from-fire)

Comment: `$firebaseObject( ref )` ftw! Because... [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html). The user's id is stored in `authUser.uid`, also [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is usually helpful to store user data like proposed in https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing.

You need to use the unique ID as the key for the user object, so you don't have to iterate over all users to search for it. The unique ID is part of the auth data, see https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication).